# Adding total on top of stacked bar graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a stacked bar graph in ggplot2. I have two questions:

How can I change the scale of the y-axis and data labels such that it shows in units of 1000 instead of 1?
Is there any way that I can make the totals of counts show on top of each bar? e.g., show 94 (thousand) in bold above bar 1 and 122 (thousand) above bar 2.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#Creating the dataset
my.data <- data.frame(dates = c("1/1/2014", "1/1/2014", "1/1/2014", "1/1/2014", "1/1/2014", "2/1/2014", "2/1/2014", "2/1/2014", "2/1/2014", "2/1/2014"),
                      fruits=c("apple", "orange", "pear", "berries", "watermelon", "apple", "orange", "pear", "berries", "watermelon"), 
                      count=c(20000, 30000, 40000, 2000, 2000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 1000, 1000))

#Creating a positon for the data labels
my.data <- 
      my.data %>%
      group_by(dates) %>%
      mutate(pos=cumsum(count)-0.5*count)

#Plotting the data
ggplot(data=my.data, aes(x=dates, y=count, fill=fruits))+      
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      geom_text(data=subset(my.data, count>10000), aes(y=pos, label=count), size=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to create the plot. First, we calculate the sum of `count` grouped by `dates`.

```
sum_count <- 
  my.data %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  summarise(max_pos = sum(count))
```

This new data frame can be used for plotting the sum on top of the bars. Changing the y-axis to units of 1000 is achieved by dividing the values by 1000.

```
ggplot(data = my.data, aes(x = dates, y = count / 1000))+      
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = fruits))+
  geom_text(data = subset(my.data, count > 10000), 
            aes(y = pos / 1000, label = count / 1000 ), size = 4) +
  geom_text(data = sum_count, 
            aes(y = max_pos / 1000, label = max_pos / 1000), size = 4,
            vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]