# Adding data labels for totals as well as class-specific values in a stacked column chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization

### Main question

When creating a stacked column chart using R's `ggplot2` library, how can I add data labels for the column totals as well as data labels for each individual class/value?

### Context

I'm trying to replicate the following graph (originally created in Excel) using R's `ggplot2` library:

[image: Original graph from Excel]

*Figure 1 - Graph Generated in Excel*

### Reproducible example & data

Here is a reproducible example of my data and the code I'm using:

```r
# Loading libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

# Creating the data.frame object
data = data.frame(year=c(2017,2017,2017,2017,
                         2018,2018,2018,2018,
                         2019,2019,2019,2019,
                         2020,2020,2020,2020,
                         2021,2021,2021,2021),
                  hsys=factor(c('Interstate Highways', 'US Highways', 'State Highways', 'FM Roads',
                                'Interstate Highways', 'US Highways', 'State Highways', 'FM Roads',
                                'Interstate Highways', 'US Highways', 'State Highways', 'FM Roads',
                                'Interstate Highways', 'US Highways', 'State Highways', 'FM Roads',
                                'Interstate Highways', 'US Highways', 'State Highways', 'FM Roads'),
                              levels = c('Interstate Highways',
                                         'US Highways',
                                         'State Highways',
                                         'FM Roads')),
                  num_crashes=c(3845,3562,3436,5749,
                                3978,3502,3565,5836,
                                4510,3692,3618,6133,
                                3517,2945,2957,4978,
                                4698,3765,3645,6158))


p = ggplot(data, 
           aes(fill=hsys, 
               y=num_crashes, 
               x=year, 
               label=format(num_crashes, 
                            big.mark = ",", 
                            decimal.mark = ".", 
                            scientific = FALSE),
           )) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", 
           stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(size=3, 
            position = position_stack(vjust=0.5,), 
            color='white',
            family = "Franklin Gothic Book",
            fontface = 'bold') + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family="Franklin Gothic Demi Cond",
                                  hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Franklin Gothic Book",),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "Franklin Gothic Book",),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(family = "Franklin Gothic Book",),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#3869A2",
                               "#0F3859",
                               "#CC7B28",
                               "#F4BC46",
                               "#79A03F"))

ggsave('hsys.jpg', p)
```

[image: Graph generated in R]

*Figure 2 - Graph Generated in R*

You'll notice that, aside from the image dimensions and font sizes not matching, they both contain almost the exact same content. The thing that's really missing are the **data labels for the column totals** at the top of each column.

### My attempt

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871390/adding-total-on-top-of-stacked-bar-graphs) seems to cover a very similar topic, but I couldn't get the solution to work.

First, I created a new `sum_count` data.frame object like this:

```r
sum_count <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(tot_crashes = sum(num_crashes))
```

And then I added a new chunk of code to my ggplot2 command between the `geom_text` and `theme` commands from the original code above:

```r
  # before this chunk, we close the first `geom_text` command
  geom_text(data = sum_count, 
            aes(y = tot_crashes, 
                label = format(tot_crashes, 
                               big.mark = ",", 
                               decimal.mark = ".", 
                               scientific = FALSE)), 
            color='black',
            family = "Franklin Gothic Book",
            fontface = 'bold',
            vjust = -0.5) +
  # after this chunk, we start the `theme` command
```

However, when I run the code which includes the new `geom_text` command described above, the code just fails with the following error:

```
Saving 8.06 x 2.89 in image
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'hsys' not found
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you specified `fill=hsys` as a global aesthetic inside `ggplot()` which is inherited by all layers. To fix that you could make `fill=hsys` a local aes of `geom_bar` or add `inherit.aes=FALSE` to `geom_text` to prevent inheritance of global aes as I do below which however requires to add `x=year` to `geom_text` too:

```
p + geom_text(data = sum_count, 
            aes(x = year,
                y = tot_crashes, 
                label = format(tot_crashes, 
                               big.mark = ",", 
                               decimal.mark = ".", 
                               scientific = FALSE)), 
            color='black',
            family = "Franklin Gothic Book",
            fontface = 'bold',
            vjust = -0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

A second approach to achieve your desired result would be to use `stat_summary` to compute the totals on the fly like so:

```
p +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "text", aes(group = 1, label = format(..y..,
      big.mark = ",",
      decimal.mark = ".",
      scientific = FALSE
    ), ), fun = "sum", color = "black",
    family = "Franklin Gothic Book",
    fontface = "bold", vjust = -0.5
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. I especially liked the on-the-fly solution you provided!!! Worked like a charm =)